# ElasticSearch suggest default set of options

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get default set of options when no input is provided to a suggest endpoint. But

```
GET /my_index/_suggest
{
   "topics": {
      "completion": {
         "field": "suggest_topic",
         "size": 10
      },
      "text": ""
   }
}
```

returns empty.

I'd like the provide the users number of options when they first opened the autocomplete field that uses this endpoint. I thought about using `/_search`  and merging the results but I think there should be a better way of doing this on ElasticSearch. [Regex query with `ANY`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)  flag seems to be a good way to solve this but they are not supported in **1.7** version.

Comment: If you don't provide an input how could Elasticsearch suggest anything? Suggestions based on what criteria? You need to have some kind of criteria...

Comment: okay lets say I want to have the most popular n items if no text is provided.  Just for convenience. I don't want to make another request and merge the results

Comment: What's your definition of "most popular"?

Comment: most popular by some field defined in the documents, so, sorted by some field. If not most popular,  I'd like to get at least the functionality achieved with regex query flags.See the link on question. I need to achieve same thing in es 1.7. (I assume it will return some documents if I regex with "*" flag). But regex input is not supported in es 1.7

Comment: Popular "items" from the `suggest_topic` field?

Comment: Just do a `terms` aggregation on that field and you will get back the most used "Terms" in that field in descending order considering the document count: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation

Comment: Depending on how you analyze that field you can get back more relevant or less relevant terms. That's why I was asking to define "popular" because you can control what terms are popular for your use case and you can define your own analyzer on the field that contains the "popular" terms. But, at the most simplest definition of "popular" you can use, as I mentioned above, a `terms` aggregation and get the first 10 popular terms from that specific field.

Answer (score 0):

Getting suggestions for an empty string is not gonna yield anything. And even if it would, I doubt it will get the results in "useful" time as a suggestions functionality should be fast so that it won't disturb user's experience.

Depending on how you analyze that field you can get back more relevant or less relevant terms. **You need to define "popular"** so you can control what terms are popular **for your use case** and you can define your own analyzer on the field that contains the "popular" terms. But, as the most simple definition of "popular" you can use a **`terms` aggregation** and get the first 10 popular terms from that specific field. "popular" here will mean **the most used terms** in your index from that specific field.

With `terms` aggregation you will get the terms in descending order considering the document count: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation

But, as I mentioned, there is no magic here. You need your own definition of "popular" and help Elasticsearch understand the same. Then, using an appropriate query you can get that list of terms/sentences etc.